# Cauchy's integral formula computation

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute
$$
\int_C \frac{|z|e^{z}}{z^{2}} \,dz,
$$
where $C$ is the circumference of the circle of radius $r$ around the origin.

I don't know how to proceed with this exercise because of the lack analyticity of the function in the numerator near $C$. What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $|z|=r$ on the circle should simplify the problem ...

Comment: Hint: $|z|$ is constant on the path of integration, so it can be pulled out of the integral as a factor of $r$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I edited your question a little bit to improve the grammar and hopefully make the source of your confusion more explicit. If the edit is not what you had in mind, you can revert the edit. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the path of integration, we have $|z|=r$, therefore
$$\int_C \frac{|z|e^z}{z^2}=r\int_C \frac{e^z}{z^2}.$$

Using [Cauchy's Integral Formula for derivatives](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/cauchy-s-integral-formula-for-derivatives) we obtain
$$r\int_C \frac{e^z}{z^2}=2\pi ir.$$